# Ubuntu 12.04.1 5.1 surround sound problem

Tags: 12.04, sound, settings

I fail to set all speakers to work on the Genius 5.1. (Such connected work well on Win 7).
I tried with alsamixer and pulseaudio but I do not succeed.

`aplay -l` gives this:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: VT1705 Analog [VT1705 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: VT1705 Digital [VT1705 Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 2: VT1705 HP [VT1705 HP]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Advance grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for my problem, so, here is what I did.

Type in terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

change the line `;default-sample-channels = 2` in to `default-sample-channels = 6`.

Do not forget to remove the `;` from the beginning of the line.

Restart the system, do a bit of settings in alsamixer and PulseAudio and everything will work just fine.